# Connecting multiple PHP containers to a single shared Elasticsearch container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, elasticsearch, docker-networking

14 PHP containers `php_1, ..., php_14` and 14 NGINX containers `nginx_1, ..., nginx_14` are running on a server. The PHP container `php_i` is only connected to `nginx_i` and all NGINX containers are connected via a shared external network. Therefore `php_i` can see `nginx_i`  and `nginx_i` can see every `nginx_j`.

A new requirement has been added to the system, and we need to have a global Elasticsearch for all projects, allowing all PHP projects to write on this single Elasticsearch instance, which is going to be installed via Docker.

To accomplish this task, the following methods have come to my mind, but I'm unsure which one is the best approach.

1. Install an isolated Elasticsearch instance and publish its port, say `9200:9200`, on the host, and in PHP configuration I set the IP of the host, say `172.17.0.1`, and port
   `9200`
2. I can create a dedicated external network for connecting PHP to Elasticsearch, and include this dedicated network in the `networks` directive of the docker-compose file.

I would like to know which method is the best practice.